# Can't mount CD/DVD on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mount, hard-drive, cd-drive

I'm a beginner in Linux and I'm trying to open a CD-ROM on Ubuntu 16.04, but I can't. I've already tried the following commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/cdrom
```

result:

```
mount: can't find /dev/cdrom in /etc/fstab
```

---

```
dmesg
```

result:

```
[ 1254.691666] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] unaligned transfer
//a lot of these lines

[ 1244.741840] EXT4-fs (sr0): unable to read superblock
[ 1244.793837] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] unaligned transfer
[ 1244.793845] EXT4-fs (sr0): unable to read superblock
[ 1244.845877] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] unaligned transfer
[ 1244.845887] EXT4-fs (sr0): unable to read superblock
[ 1244.901832] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] unaligned transfer
[ 1244.901838] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x0
[ 1244.901840] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: unable to read squashfs_super_block
[ 1254.689544] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#19 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1254.689548] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#19 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 1254.689550] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#19 Add. Sense: Head select fault
[ 1254.689553] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#19 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[ 1254.689555] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
```

I put this line in `fstab`, restarted and it didn't work:

```
#/dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom iso9660 ro,user,noauto,unhide 0 0
```

When I enter with eject, it ejects normally.

What do I do to open this CD?

Comment: Remove the hash from the fstab line. A hash means a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax of `mount` is wrong. Remove whatever you added to *fstab*. Then try

```
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
```

If CD-ROM appears under /mnt folder - fine, adjust to your needs. If not - you will get proper error description. Most likely not, because CD-ROM mounting in Ubuntu should be automatic.
P.S. Whatever instructions you use - they are outdated. Use `journalctl` instead of `dmesg`

Comment: I get this:
 mount: /dev/sr0: can't read superblock
I only want to open a simple data DVD (phisical not ISO), do I really need to enter with all these commands? I can't find it anywhere in my files or computer wuen I put the DVD.

Comment: It looks like either cd-rom can't read this disc or linux core has problems using this cd-rom. Are you sure disc is OK?

Comment: Yes, it opens on windows normally, my Ubuntu is 16.04 LTS how could I know I have to install any driver?

Comment: I get some problem, if anyone found the solution?